# How do you deal with logging out a user with multiple tabs open when a session ends?

Tags: javascript, session

We want to log the user out when the session ends, so one approach is to have JavaScript redirect the user to the logout script after the time period of the session passes. If the user has multiple tabs open, however, the JavaScript can activate on a tab that isn't visible and log the user out. We can't do an AJAX call because that would reset the session time length. What's a good approach to dealing with logging out a user with multiple tabs open when the session ends?

EDIT: The session expires on the server after a time length. The JavaScript is just there to redirect the user to the logout page so that the content does not stay on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expire the session cookie. Cookies can be set to expire at browser close or after a certain period of time. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age

Answer (score 1):

You have to poll the server if the user is logged in. You can do it per AJAX or WebSockets. Maybe you can automatically redirect if the cookie is expired but I don't know exactly if you can check the expiry date per JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you rely on javascript for this? Log him out on a server and then open tabs don't matter.

Comment: I just edited the question. We are only using javascript because we want the user redirected to a login page.

Answer (score 0):

I've a MVC application, On successful Login I set a login Storage value in my Layout.cshtml

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loginStorageChange(event) {
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('loginStorage') === null) {
            setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 1000);
        }
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('loginStorage', true);
    window.addEventListener('storage', loginStorageChange, false);
});
```

On Logout Click, I remove the loginStorage before form submit

```
function logoutSubmit() {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('loginStorage');
    $('#logoutForm').submit();
}
```

So when window detects that loginstorage has been changed so it reloads the page, Server indicates a logout and redirects to login page.